# Comparing a list of date to a current date that is any how many dates in list are equal to currentdate

Tags: java, date-comparison, date

Want to compare a list of date (get it one by one and compare it with the current date of today and get how many dates are equal to the current date
if they are equal `get flag=1` and use it

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView showdate() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test");

    List<Date> newDate = new ArrayList<Date>();
    newDate = studentDao.Datelist();

    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(millis);

    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(newDate);

    int flag = 0;
    for (Date newDate1 : newDate) { //for each construct
        // Enter code here
        System.out.println(newDate1);

        if (date.compareTo(newDate1) == 0) {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1) {
        System.out.println("date is equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("date is not equal");
    }

    return model;
}
```

Comment: this is the main problem are please provide the solution of it

Comment: not getting flag==1 by comapring dates

Comment: Have you tried `if (date.equals(newDate1))` instead of `if (date.compareTo(newDate1) == 0)`? I recommend not to use `java.util.Date` but switch to `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: I recommend you use neither `java.sql.Date` nor `java.util.Date`. Both are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` throughout.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Date` contains time details as well (hours/minutes/seconds) etc. surely you can see that when you print the date variable. is so you will need to get the date part only.  Another issue is usage of this old (obsolete) class. It has been replaced by `java.time` classes since java 7.

```
// converting java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate 
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

instances of LocalDate do not contain time details and can be safely compared.

**EDIT**

converting `java.sql.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate` is straightforward with [`toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--)

Comment: getting list of dates from mysql database which is in java.sql.date so not able to parse it in java.util.date how to compare two dates of java.sql.date

Comment: Get `LocalDate` objects from the database. In you DAO class do `yourResultSet.getObject(1, LocalDate.class)` to retrieve a date from column 1 of the query.

Comment: @kartik You should not be throwing in new requirements (database) iin a comment. Make the effort to think through your question with all pertinent facts and constraints documented up front *before* posting. Voting to now close as "Unclear".